# How do I check if an input field value contains a character?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
 var email = document.querySelector('#issueContactEmail');


 if (email.value.includes('@')) {
    console.log('has @');
    return valid;
}
```

I have a form with an input with the id of issueContactEmail

I would like to check if there is an @ symbol in the input value before the user can go forward.
My code here does not seem to work.

How else can I check this?
If you could briefly explain why this doesn't work that would be great too! thank you in advance

Comment: Cannot reproduce. https://jsfiddle.net/fnsxt7dp/ Post a [MCVE]. Put the check inside some listener if it isn't already, don't run the check on page load

Comment: I assume you're using a somewhat modern browser, correct? IE, for example, does not support `includes`.

Comment: How is the code not working?  are you getting any errors, perhaps indicating if the value is undefined, or whether includes exists (indexOf is an alternative)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few possibilities on why this code is not working for you. The first is that your javascript is running before the document has fully loaded (ie #issueContactEmail is not present in the DOM when your javascript tries to access it).
Consider moving your javascript to the end of your `<body>` tag if possible, to eliminate that issue.

Another possibility is that the browser you're running this code in does not offer/support the `.includes()` method that you're trying to use (this will be the case in some older browsers)

Perhaps you could try the following code, that puts in place a few additional safety checks to avoid the later issue:

```
var email = document.querySelector('#issueContactEmail');
var valid = false;

if(email) { // Check if input#issueContactEmail field exists
  if(email.value && email.value.contains('@')) { // Check if field value
                                                 // exists and contains '@'

    valid = true; // Then the field value is considered valid
  }
}

return valid; // Return if the field value was considered valid
```

[Here's a jsFiddle as well](https://jsfiddle.net/fnsxt7dp/4/) - hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
//Takes the value form the input field
var email = document.querySelector('#issueContactEmail');
//returns weather this is a valid input value(contains @ sysmble)
return email.value && email.value.contains('@');
```